# Number of regions created by r hyper-planes in n-dimensional space

Tags: co.combinatorics, complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I found this formula for calculating maximum number of regions created by **r** hyper-planes in **n-dimensional space** (n<=r)

```
                      rC0 + rC1 + ....... + rCn
```

How can this formula be proved??

Comment: The number of regions depends on the particular hyperplanes. I think your formula is for *generic* hyperplanes.

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes, I guess it's for the maximum number of regions that any r hyperplanes can make in n-dimensional space

Comment: Please use TeX on this site.

Comment: These should be some type of cake numbers. There is also a result what happens if some of them are parallel, see the works by Wetzel. Also: https://jlmartin.ku.edu/MiniCollege2012/slides.pdf

Answer (score 5):

One proof is in my book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second ed., Proposition 3.11.8. The first proof is due to L. Schläfli, written in 1850-52 but not published until 1901 in *Neue allgemeinen schweizerischen Gesellschaft für die gesamten Naturwissenschaften*, vol. 38, IV, Zurich, 1901.